# Artificialy create massive page fault

Tags: memory-management, window

Is there a way to make a windows process have soo many page faults that it would us an excessive amount of CPU?

The idea is to make windows waste time pulling the pages to the memory, while having the process itself not have that CPU usage atributed to it.

Comment: Do you want the disk to be exercised (as in "pulling the pages to the memory") or is it just that you want the vast majority of the process's time to be spent inside the kernel?

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to make a process force the kernel CPU to max out while looking perfectly innocent and harmless.

Comment: Exactly, since I believe that time used on pullig pages do not show on process usage.